# undefined Refence in CMakeLists

Tags: c++, android-studio, cmake, webrtc

I want to build the webRTC using the CMakeLists.txt and then use it in my android studio.
I have made the CMakeLists.txt in each subdirectory.

**SubDiretory CMakeLists:**

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.4.1)
set(SRC_FILES
        //Here are all my .cc and .cpp source files
)



add_subdirectory(audio_processing)    //this is another subdirectory in folder in which i have made a CMakeLists.txt file.
add_library(webrtc_modules ${SRC_FILES})
target_link_libraries(webrtc_modules webrtc_modules_audio_processing)

target_include_directories(webrtc_modules PUBLIC
        //these are the directories in which I want my programs to look for the header files

        async_audio_processing
        audio_coding
        audio_device
        audio_mixer
        audio_processing
        congestion_controller
        desktop_capture
        include
        pacing
        remote_bitrate_estimator
        rtp_rtcp
        third_party
        utility
        video_capture
        video_coding
        video_processing
)
```

I am linking this library into Main CMakeLists.txt

**Main CMakeLists:**

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.10)


set(LOCAL_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} std=c++17")
set(CMAKE_C_FLAGS "${CMAKE_C_FLAGS} -DWEBRTC_POSIX -O0 -DWEBRTC_ANDROID")

include_directories(modules)

link_directories(modules)

add_subdirectory(modules)





set(STATIC_LIBS webrtc_modules)

add_library(libwebrtc)

target_link_libraries(libwebrtc PUBLIC ${STATIC_LIBS})
```

Library build successfully but when I call any function of this subDirectory then it gives me **Undefined reference**.
Can you please tell me how to solve this issue?
Any help in this regard will be highly appreciated.

Comment: Undefined reference error is given my CMake or C++ compiler? Did you test it linking it with `main.cpp`?

Comment: Please, add into the question post the **exact error message**.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, when the different static libraries doesn't properly link to the main shared library then this issue occurs. To solve that we should link our static libraries using this flag
**target_link_libraries()** flag of CmakeLists.txt and the issue  resolved.
So, apply target_link_libraries() flag in subdirectory CmakeLists.txt and link the static libraries together.